# Fabric js. How to do I make control corner visible AND disable function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas, fabricjs

I am trying to:

- Make the top left control corner visible but nonfunctional
- Transform that top left corner control into a small image
- Make the top left corner control show when hovering over the object

It seems like when I disable the top left control corner, it loses its visibility. Scaling will be done with buttons instead of the control corners.

Here is the JSfiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/gmeoe14c/1/

```
fabric.Object.prototype.objectCaching = false;
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas');

var triangle = new fabric.Triangle({
   fill: 'green',
   left: 200,
   top: 200,
   padding: 5,
   hasBorders: false,
   cornerColor: 'black'
});

canvas.add(triangle);
canvas.renderAll();

triangle.setControlsVisibility({
  tr: false,
  br: false,
  bl: false,
  ml: false,
  mt: false,
  mr: false,
  mb: false,
  mtr: false
});
```

Comment: I tried adding

'triangle.lockScalingX = true;
trianble.lockScalingY = true;'

but as I hover over the top left control corner.. the mouse cursor turns into a expander.

How do I get rid of the mouse cursor expander???